# SQL grouping/counting on a string split function

Tags: sql, legacy-sql

Ok so my original is this

```
select people, count(*) 
from table
group by people
```

but some of the people have multiple people so this aggregation will not give you pure counts for A, B, C but also each iteration

```
A 10
B 5
A, B 1
A, C 2
C 15
A, B, C 3
```

etc.

This works to get the full list of individuals in legacy sql

```
select split(people,",") as person
from table
```

But I cannot use the group by on it

```
select split(people,",") as person, count(*)
from table
group by person
```

gives the error

> Cannot group by an aggregate.

I feel like the solution is a subquery, somehow, but I'm not sure how to execute it

Comment: Why are you using legacy SQL and not Standard SQL?

Comment: which rdbms are you using

Comment: I'm working in bigquery and I get "you cannot use standard sql against a legacy sql view" errors if I switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrap with an outer query

```
select person, count(*)
from(
    select split(people,",") as person
    from table
) t
group by person
```